# Proper project organization with common source files and sub-projects

Tags: c, svn, makefile

I have a straight C project that builds several different inter-related modules into a single image using a single top-level makefile and recursive calls to the modules.  This all works fine, although I know it's not using the best structure.  I now need to restructure it because of some changes to the project, and I'd like to do it "right".  In addition, I've found that I'm using some common code in the modules that right now is just copied into each one, so I'd like to fix that too.

The further complication is that I'm using Subversion and the common code that's being used is stored in a separate repo from the project, so I can't just import each file that's used.

Here is the structure I think I'd like to use, but I'm not completely sure how to write the makefiles to actually work with it (but I can handle that in another question if needed).

```
build
 +  common
 |   +  lib1
 |   +  lib2
 +  module1
 |   +  obj
 +  module2
 |   +  obj
 +  module3
 |   +  obj
 +  output
```

Common would be an external to a folder in the other repo that has the common source files, and the makefile in each module would build intermediate object files locally (this is required as each module compiles differently, so the common files are not common binaries) and then put its final binary in the shared output directory for the top level makefile to combine into the single final image.

1. Is this a reasonable structure to use for make to deal with?
2. Module 1 uses a third-party library that may be switched out later.  Should it be a sub-directory of module1, or should it be in common (hard to do with subversion, unless I mix it into the folder on the other repo), or should it be added as another directory under build?
3. Module 2 compiles to a static library for Module 3 to use.  Should Module 3's makefile explicitly know about Module 2 or should the header file be in the common directory (the library will be in the output directory already)?
4. There are other common definitions that this project needs to set up for all the modules, which would ordinarily be in a header file in the common directory, but since that directory is coming from a subversion external, what are my other options for doing this?

Comment: You have multiple modules, sharing a common source file, each compiling it differently, and then you link the binaries. That doesn't sound good at all, and think there's more to that story.

Comment: @Beta they are only sharing some files, like logging functions or CRC handling functions.  Each module is running on its own in a virtual machine, and all the VMs are bound together into one image to load onto the embedded device.

Answer (score 0):

First, some of these design questions are matters of taste and habit, and arguments about them can verge on religious war.

Second, your `common` directory is poorly named, since it serves specifically as a store of the code from the other repository (a good thing to have), and not as a place for all sources shared by multiple modules (a *different* good thing to have). So I suggest you add another directory such as `build/headers/`, for headers that are common to more than one module, but are stored in your own repository.

1. Yes, once you add headers/.

   A subdir of module1/ is a good place for it; if the other modules don't use it, there's no reason for them to be able to see it.

   headers/ is literally made for this. Put the header there. Module 3 has no business knowing more about Module 2's implementation than that.

   Again, headers/ is the place for them.

Comment: This is all fine, but it's not just headers in the common folder, it's source files too.